# the input is repeated in the file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write (append) some input from a user like this :

ID : 0001

Name : Mohab

Age : 20

Sex : Male

E-Mail : mohab@server.com

Address : Cairo

and every time I receive an input from I user i send it to the function via object like :

```
snd.append(some input);
```

Now the function responsible for the appending is :

```
bool FMS::append(string data)
{
fstream myfile;
myfile.open("Employee.txt",ios::app);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    myfile << data << endl;
    myfile.close();
    return true;
}
else
    return false;
}
```

but every time a save an Employee's Info in file it reserve like this :

```
1
Mohab
120
Male
Male
mohab@server.com
Cairo
```

for those how ask .. this is the code :

```
                    cout << "Enter the ID : ";
                cin >> emp.ID;
                convert << emp.ID;
                IDS= convert.str();
                snd.append(IDS);
                cout << "Enter The Employee's Name : ";
                cin >> emp.name;
                snd.append(emp.name);
                while(1)
                {
                    cout << "Enter the Age : ";
                    cin >> tempage;
                    value2 = emp.setAge(tempage);
                    if(value2==true)
                    {
                        convert << tempage;
                        IDS= convert.str();
                        snd.append(IDS);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Invalid Age!\n";
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                while(1)
                {
                    cout << "Enter the Gender : ";
                    cin >> tempgender;
                    snd.append(tempgender);
                    value2=emp.setGender(tempgender);
                    if(value2==true)
                    {
                        snd.append(tempgender);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Invalid Gender!\n";
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                cout << "Enter E-Mail : ";
                cin >> emp.mail;
                snd.append(emp.mail);
                cout << "Enter the Address : ";
                cin >> emp.address;
                value2=snd.append(emp.address);
                if(value2==true)
                    cout << "Successful Registration\n";
                else 
                    cout << "Register Failed\n";
```

why this happened do think ?!!
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Show us how you call `append`.

Comment: like this :

cin >> tempgender;     snd.append(tempgender);

??

Comment: We need more context than that. Show us your `main` function please.

Answer (score 0):

You write the gender to the file two times:

```
cout << "Enter the Gender : ";
cin >> tempgender;

//FIRST TIME HERE               
snd.append(tempgender);

value2=emp.setGender(tempgender);
if(value2==true)
{
    //SECOND TIME HERE
    snd.append(tempgender);
    break;
}
```

EDIT: The error in the age probalby comes from using `convert` for both the ID and the age without resetting it in between. So the `<<` appends the age to the ID instead of replacing it.

Comment: and what about the age sir ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. See my edit for my guess about this error. However, this depends on what `convert` exectly is.